# Approximation to $n$ decimal places

Tags: calculus, derivatives, taylor-expansion, power-series

There is an exercise in howard Anton which says to approximate the value of $\sin 3^{\circ}$ upto $3$ decimal places using Maclaurin series. There the lagranges form of remainder has been used to bound the error. But as the question says to approximate the result upto $5$
decimal places, they concluded that the error $|R_n(\frac{\pi}{60})| \le 0.000005$.

*I couldn't follow why the error has to be less than $5 \times 10^{-6}$ (($1 \times 10^{-6}$) in some other books) and why it is guaranteed to be appropriate to $5$
decimal places.*

No explanation has been given,and this bound seems out of the blue. I also searched on the internet and found a statement that approximation to $n$ decimal places implies error to be less than $0.5 \times 10^{n}$. An intuitive explanation with some examples will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three decimals corresponds to having a number like $0.345$ correct as a rounded value.  The $5$ is in the third place and corresponds to $5 \cdot 10^{-3}$.  The neighboring value is $0.346$, a difference of $0.001$, so if you are closer to $0.345$ than any other three decimal number you are within $\pm 0.0005=5 \cdot 10^{-(3+1)}$.

When the true value is near the breakpoint you can be within this error bound and round to the incorrect value.  For example, let the true value be $0.34551$.  This rounds to $0.346$, but if you calculated $0.34547$, which is within the error bound, it will round to $0.345$.  This is an edge case which we ignore when we talk of having three decimals.

Comment: Could you please explain the first paragraph a bit more with another example of a number not having $5$ at the end?I didn't actually get the line where you said "If you are closer to $0.345$ than any other three decimal number,you are within $5\times 10^{-(3+1)}$.

Comment: I wrote the exponent that way to indicate that it is $n+1$ when you want an answer to $n$ places.  There is nothing special of having $5$ at the end.  The next three place number above $0.237$ is $0.238$.  The difference is $0.001$ and half that is $0.0005$ so for $0.237$ to be the closest approximation you need to be in the range $(0.2365, 0.2375)$

Comment: Thank you for clearing out. Another question,why are we taking only half of the difference?Why not any other fraction like one fourth or three fourth? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Because you are trying to find the closest three decimal number to the actual value.  You take a half so they meet in the middle.  If you measure something to the nearest inch you break the ranges at $1/2$ inch for that reason.